# how to read parquet metadata for pyarrow Dataset

Tags: metadata, dask, pyarrow, fastparquet

I have a process that saved a `dask` dataframe to parquet.  The result is a directory with the name `xxxxx.parquet` inside of which are 73 individual `.parquet` files.  I would like to get the metadata of the parquet files.

If I use `fastparquet` it has an `.info()` method that treats the directory like a single file.  So I can do `fp.ParquetFile(xxxxx.parquet).info['rows']` and it will return the number of rows in the entire data set.

I can't seem to find an equivalent functionality in `pyarrow` which I have to use instead of `fastparquet`.  Is there one?

Comment: "pyarrow which I have to use" - pity :)